# Number of sessions in #standardsql Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

Im looking to convert this Bigquery #legacySQL query into #standardsql.

```
#legacySQL
SELECT SUM(totals.visits) AS Sessions, 
COUNT(DISTINCT(fullVisitorID), 2000000) as Distinct_Users #this doesn't include null values and I've increased the sample size to 2000000 (Learn more)
FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([0123456789.ga_sessions_],TIMESTAMP('2017-01-01'),TIMESTAMP('2017-03-13'))
```

So far i got number of users correct but struggling to get number of sessions right:

```
#standardsql
SELECT 
count(distinct fullvisitorid)
,SUM(totals.visits) AS Sessions
FROM `ga-export-1111.0123456789.ga_sessions_2017*`
,UNNEST (hits) AS hits
```

It is 14th of March now so date condition is fine.

I guess it is because of repeated fields it shows inflated number of sessions. Can anyone help with syntax question please?

Comment: You standardSQL query has extra aggregation for "case when hits.isInteraction = TRUE then visitId else null end" which is not there for legacySQL. What do you want to count there ?

Comment: @Mosha, oh just ignore it (i forgot to remove it and will do now).  The question is about SUM(totals.visits) AS Sessions.

Comment: The reason I asked about it, is because that was the clause that forced you to flatten hits - which in turn inflated counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unnest was unnecessary. This will work as intendent:

```
#standardsql
SELECT 
count(distinct fullvisitorid)

,SUM(totals.visits) AS Sessions
FROM `ga-export-1111.0123456789.ga_sessions_2017*`
```